# How to continue performing asynchronous actions after return in php?

Tags: php, asynchronous, response, nonblocking, amphp

I'm just a beginner, please tell me if it is possible to return the result from a php function, but at the same time so that asynchronous actions continue to work in it using the amphp library?

example:

```
function run () {

    $func1 = function () {
        //the main action from which you need to get an answer
        $result = "Result";
        
        return $result;
    };
    
    
    $future1 = Amp\async(function () {
        
        Amp\delay(3);
        //not the main action
        echo 'DB, or any Request';
        
    });
    
    $future1->await();
    
    return $func1();

};

run();
```

Let's assume that the "run" function accepts a request, func1 implies actions that need to be performed and based on them return a response to the client, future1 are actions that we do not need to wait for to return a response to the client.

Well, this is the main question, how to achieve this behavior? Any tips, links, directions, explanations

Comment: Just to be sure, you actually mean that you're a beginning AMPHP user, and _not_ a beginning PHP user? If the latter is true you shouldn't be using AMPHP.

Comment: why not? 
I will not say that I am a pro in php, but I know and understand some things.
rather I meant in amphp

Comment: Why? Running processes asynchronous can be very normal in languages like Javascript. Everything there is event driven. PHP clearly doesn't work like that. Only in exceptional circumstances would you need to run processes asynchronous in PHP. As to your question: If you wait for a process to end, inside a function, then that function will only return when that process is finished.